# Issue trying to combine mkv with SRT subtitles

Tags: ffmpeg, subtitles, matroska

Am facing this issue when trying to embed subtitles into mkv format.

```
ffmpeg -i Silence2016.mkv English.srt -map 0 -map 1 -c copy output.mkv
ffmpeg version 3.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 6.0 (clang-600.0.57) (based on LLVM 3.5svn)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.2.2 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --disable-lzma --enable-nonfree --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 34.100 / 55. 34.100
  libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
  libavformat    57. 56.100 / 57. 56.100
  libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
  libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
  libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
  libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
  libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
  libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
Input #0, matroska,webm, from 'Silence2016.mkv':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : libebml v1.3.3 + libmatroska v1.4.4
    creation_time   : 2017-03-14T12:39:18.000000Z
  Duration: 02:41:24.47, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3935 kb/s
    Chapter #0:0: start 0.000000, end 779.000000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 1
    Chapter #0:1: start 779.000000, end 1334.000000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 2
    Chapter #0:2: start 1334.000000, end 2000.000000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 3
    Chapter #0:3: start 2000.000000, end 2517.000000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 4
    Chapter #0:4: start 2517.000000, end 3073.000000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 5
    Chapter #0:5: start 3073.000000, end 3794.000000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 6
    Chapter #0:6: start 3794.000000, end 4256.000000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 7
    Chapter #0:7: start 4256.000000, end 4978.000000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 8
    Chapter #0:8: start 4978.000000, end 5419.000000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 9
    Chapter #0:9: start 5419.000000, end 6108.000000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 10
    Chapter #0:10: start 6108.000000, end 6476.000000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 11
    Chapter #0:11: start 6476.000000, end 6885.000000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 12
    Chapter #0:12: start 6885.000000, end 7836.000000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 13
    Chapter #0:13: start 7836.000000, end 8350.000000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 14
    Chapter #0:14: start 8350.000000, end 9261.000000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 15
    Chapter #0:15: start 9261.000000, end 9684.467000
    Metadata:
      title           : Chapter 16
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1916x800 [SAR 1:1 DAR 479:200], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 3550456
      BPS-eng         : 3550456
      DURATION        : 02:41:24.467000000
      DURATION-eng    : 02:41:24.467000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 232195
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 232195
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 4298035203
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 4298035203
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v8.5.2 ('Crosses') 32bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v8.5.2 ('Crosses') 32bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2017-03-14 12:39:18
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2017-03-14 12:39:18
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: ac3, 48000 Hz, 5.1(side), fltp, 384 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      BPS             : 384000
      BPS-eng         : 384000
      DURATION        : 02:41:07.616000000
      DURATION-eng    : 02:41:07.616000000
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES: 302113
      NUMBER_OF_FRAMES-eng: 302113
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES : 464045568
      NUMBER_OF_BYTES-eng: 464045568
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP: mkvmerge v8.5.2 ('Crosses') 32bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_APP-eng: mkvmerge v8.5.2 ('Crosses') 32bit
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC: 2017-03-14 12:39:18
      _STATISTICS_WRITING_DATE_UTC-eng: 2017-03-14 12:39:18
      _STATISTICS_TAGS: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
      _STATISTICS_TAGS-eng: BPS DURATION NUMBER_OF_FRAMES NUMBER_OF_BYTES
Output #0, srt, to 'English.srt':
Output file #0 does not contain any stream
```

Any ideas on what going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your command,

```
ffmpeg -i Silence2016.mkv English.srt -map 0 -map 1 -c copy output.mkv
```

there's no `-i` before the SRT filename, so ffmpeg thinks it's the name of your output file. Normally, ffmpeg would select a stream from among the inputs that could be muxed into the output, but since the MKV has no subs, there's no streams to transcode. Unfortunately, the SRT has almost certainly been wiped out when ffmpeg opened it for writing.

If you have a backup of the SRT, use

```
ffmpeg -i Silence2016.mkv -i English.srt -map 0 -map 1 -c copy output.mkv
```